# In martix project in R ,how would you retrieve the bottom-left item?

Tags: r

With a matrix object, Sales of 5x5 , how can retrieve bottom left item ?

Answer (score 1):

"bottom left" in the usual matrix context means "last row, first column", so

```
Sales[nrow(Sales),1]
```

or

```
tail(x,1)[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

In R you can think of a matrix as a list with starting index to be 1 and calling `matrix[row, col]`.

Therefore, you can take the bottom left item with `Sales[5,1]`.

Comment: for getting the entire row or col you can leave the space blank such as `matrix[row,]` this will get the entire row specified with all columns values.

Comment: @BenBolker yes! Thank you! Sales[5,1]